# Dispose h2 database after @DataJpaTest

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-boot-test

I have a lot of Test classes annotated with Spring Boot's `@DataJpaTest`. For each of those classes, a new h2 database is being created and a set of `liquibase` scripts are being executed. Then the tests run.

The problem with this setup is that after each test class execution, the database that was created and used, remains in-memory. After 20-some test classes, I run out of memory. I'd like to dispose the database once my test class is done with it.

I [read](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases) that `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0` will force the database to be closed after the last connections is closed. I believe when a test class is finished with, the Spring's `DataSource` will close all connections, *however* I don't see a way to set this property in the connection string. [Here's where](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java#L64) the "magic" happens.

Any suggestions?